# Error Switching geom_tile plot to Stat_Density_2D Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, heatmap

I have been attempting to make a heat map with the following data.

Data:

```
 structure(list(platelocheight = c(2.594, 3.803, 3.254, 3.599, 
3.617, 3.297, 2.093, 3.611, 2.842, 3.316, 2.872, 3.228, 3.633, 
4.28, 3.309, 2.8, 2.632, 3.754, 2.207, 3.604, 3.443, 2.188, 3.452, 
2.553, 3.382, 3.067, 2.986, 2.785, 2.567, 3.804), platelocside = c(0.059, 
-1.596, -0.65, -0.782, -0.301, -0.104, 0.057, -0.807, 0.003, 
1.661, 0.088, -0.32, -1.115, -0.146, -0.364, -0.952, 0.254, 0.109, 
-0.671, -0.803, -0.212, -0.069, -0.09, -0.472, 0.434, 0.337, 
0.723, 0.508, -0.197, -0.635), exitspeed = c(69.891, 73.352, 
83.942, 85.67, 79.454, 85.277, 81.078, 73.573, 77.272, 59.263, 
97.343, 91.436, 76.264, 83.479, 47.576, 84.13, 60.475, 61.093, 
84.54, 69.959, 88.729, 88.019, 82.18, 83.684, 86.296, 90.605, 
79.945, 59.899, 62.522, 77.75)), .Names = c("platelocheight", 
"platelocside", "exitspeed"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I first created a geom_tile heatmap with this code which ran successfully.

```
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)


con=odbcConnect('username',uid='userid', pwd = 'password')

df=sqlQuery(con,"select platelocheight, platelocside, exitspeed from pitches_sample where pitchcall='InPlay' 
and exitspeed is not null")

topKzone <- 3.5
botKzone <- 1.6
inKzone <- -0.95
outKzone <- 0.95
kZone <- data.frame(
  x=c(inKzone, inKzone, outKzone, outKzone, inKzone),
  y=c(botKzone, topKzone, topKzone, botKzone, botKzone)
)

df$h <- round(df$platelocheight)
df$s <- round(df$platelocside)

ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x=s, y=h, fill=exitspeed)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

The code produces this plot:
[image]

I like the structure of the plot, but I think the style/appearance is too tile-like. In a perfect world, I would like to create a plot that looks similar to this.

[image]

To accomplish this, I have taken people's advice on stackoverflow and attempted to create a stat_density_2D plot with the code below.

```
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)


con=odbcConnect('username',uid='userid', pwd = 'password')

df=sqlQuery(con,"select platelocheight, platelocside, exitspeed from pitches_sample where pitchcall='InPlay' 
            and exitspeed is not null")

topKzone <- 3.5
botKzone <- 1.6
inKzone <- -0.95
outKzone <- 0.95
kZone <- data.frame(
  x=c(inKzone, inKzone, outKzone, outKzone, inKzone),
  y=c(botKzone, topKzone, topKzone, botKzone, botKzone)
)

df$h <- round(df$platelocheight)
df$s <- round(df$platelocside)
df$es<- round(df$exitspeed)

ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) +
  stat_density_2d(data=df, aes(x=s, y=h, fill=es),geom="polygon") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

The code produces a plot with the output below, but as you can see, it is only one color and it does not display the exitspeed color contour like the geom_tile plot did.

[image]

I have tried a variety of different plots inlcuding geom_ratser and stat_contour to try and get these plots to work, but I am struggling to find a way to get the code to properly account for my fill variable (exitspeed). The code either runs and produces a single-color plot or I get the error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'exitspeed' not found
```

Does anyone know how to properly alter a geom_tile heatmap so that the output can look more like a stat_density_2D plot? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set up a new grid and interpolate your data to the new grid. That will make it look less rectangle-y.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(sp)

new_map <- df %>% rename(x = s, y = h)
coordinates(new_map) <- ~x + y
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = -3, to = 3, by = .1), y = seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = .1))
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y 
gridded(grd) <- TRUE 
idw <- idw(formula = exitspeed ~ 1, locations = new_map, newdata = grd) 
idw.output <- as.data.frame(idw)

ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_tile(data=idw.output, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=var1.pred)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(10, "Spectral")), breaks = c(60, 70, 80, 90, 100), labels = c(60, 70, 80, 90, 100), limits = c(60,100))+
    geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
    labs(fill = "ExitSpeed")+
    coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: That worked great, thanks! Quick follow up question(s). Is it possible to change the title from var1.pred to ExitSpeed and change the range of var1.pred from 60-100, where the range increases by 10 (60,70,80,90,100)? I know that may seem simple, but I am not following in your code where you could change that since the first time you call the var1.pred variable is in the ggplot line. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer now. The "var1.pred" is generae during the idw() command.

Comment: You can change the legend title using `labs()` and you can change breaks and labels in your `scale_*_gradient()` calls.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for the help! It is much appreciated!